# Right way to create html forms (input select)

Tags: php, html, forms, web

I'm trying to understand how to create html forms.
The main problem that worries me - change input value using Developer console (for example select inputs)

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="0">ex 1</option>
  <option value="1">ex 2</option>
</select>
```

User just can press F12 and change value that is submit to the server:

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="99999">ex 1</option>
  <option value="12345">ex 2</option>
</select>
```

As a result, the wrong value will be submit to the server.
How to fix this problem?
I understand that you can check the allowed values on the server but what if there are a lot of options?
I saw the sites on which the forms are implemented and if there is a change in the value in this way, the server will still correctly process the incoming data (the correct data will be displayed or the correct form will be loaded via AJAX). I do not understand how the form ignores the value change through the Developer console.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Validation on the back-end is important. You won't be able to stop anyone from adjusting the HTML on the front-end.

Comment: Never trust the user, so backend validation is mandatory whatever frontend you're using.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, any well-crafted form will **NEVER** rely on client-side validation (CSV). The only purpose of CSV is to provide instant feedback to the user; for example, for required fields, or required values (e.g., no negative quantities).  A shopping cart form will never rely on the price returned from the client, but only care about item id and quantity. The actual price calculation will take place on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this should be a comment as this question is broad, but character limit etc...

If you only want the user to be able to select from a predefined list, implement exactly that behaviour in your back end validation.

For example:

```
$allowed_values = [0,1];

if (!in_array($_GET['select'], $allowed_values) {
   die('Please select a valid option');
}
```

If they submit anything else other than what you've specified, don't let your system progress.

Ideally don't just dump them on some blank page with an error message, I'd recommend gracefully returning them to your form and highlight what part was invalid.

Always validate anything submitted, there's plenty of different [good/bad examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP%20form%20validation) (broad question) on the subject.

You can of course implement client side validation with [JS](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20form%20validation) or some things can be done directly in [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required) which would be an a better experience for the user, but it's just as easily manipulated, so if you go down that route it should be done in addition to your PHP validation, not instead of.

Comment: It's good, but what if the select have 100+ options? In this case, create an allowed values array with 100+ elements?
Or if the values are taken from the database. Then check the submitted value using db query with this value?

Comment: If you have 100+ different options you probably want to choose a different element than a select as that would be terrible for a user to use. But yeah same logic, you will have to either check against a pre-defined list of "allowed" values, or come up with a rule that would result in the same, eg: If the user was selecting a score of 0-100 you could just check that the submitted value is a number in that range rather than every value individually.

Answer (score 0):

Check server side if the send value exist, list all possible values in database or in constant and check with the send value.

(sorry for my english)